# Why does `*` on a subclass of `String` return the receiver's class?

Tags: ruby, string

If I make a subclass of `String`, `*` returns an instance of that class.

```
class MyString < String
end

MyString.new("foo").*(2).class #=> MyString
```

This is different from other similar operations like `+` and `%`, which return a `String` instance.

```
MyString.new("foo").+("bar").class #=> String
MyString.new("%{foo}").%(foo: "bar").class #=> String
```

Why does `*` behave different from `+` and `%`?

Comment: Core classes are typically not meant to be inherited from. While there are sometimes patches to make them behave consistently in the face of inheritance, often performance and other reasons are out before that. Thus, built-in methods often have unpredictable behaviour here (which can change between Ruby versions). In order to be safe, you should overwrite the methods and ensure that you return consistent classes, e.g. by using `MyString.new(super)`.

Comment: That said, you probably don't want to inherit from core classes at all, esp. not from the basic types like `Hash`, `Array`, `String`, `Numeric`, ... Often, it is cleaner and less confusing to use a decorator instead (i.e wrap the string into your class and delegate method calls to it)

Comment: @HolgerJust Inheriting from core classes is useful when you want to add functions to it without messing the original class.

Comment: In Ruby 2.1 and later, there are refinements for this exact use-case. However, the feature is a bit confusing on its own and seldom used. As I said, it it probably cleaner to use a decorator instead of a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

The unsatisfying answer is … because it's implemented that way.

Here's [the implementation](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/string.rb#L75-79) of [`String#+`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-2B) in [Rubinius](http://Rubini.us/):

```
def +(other)
  other = StringValue(other)
  Rubinius::Type.compatible_encoding self, other
  String.new(self) << other
end
```

As you can see, it explicitly constructs a `String`, that's why it always returns a `String`.

Here's [the implementation](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/string.rb#L52-58) of [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-25) in Rubinius:

```
def %(args)
  *args = args
  ret = Rubinius::Sprinter.get(self).call(*args)

  ret.taint if tainted?
  return ret
end
```

It uses the [`Rubinius::Sprinter`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/sprinter.rb) for formatting the `String`, which always returns a `String`.

And finally, here's [the implementation](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/string.rb#L60-73) of [`String#*`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-2A) in Rubinius:

```
def *(num)
  num = Rubinius::Type.coerce_to(num, Integer, :to_int) unless num.kind_of? Integer

  if num.kind_of? Bignum
    raise RangeError, "bignum too big to convert into `long' (#{num})"
  end

  if num < 0
    raise ArgumentError, "unable to multiple negative times (#{num})"
  end

  str = self.class.pattern num * @num_bytes, self
  return str
end
```

The interesting part here is that it tries to find a class method not by calling `String.pattern`, but by calling `self.class.pattern`, so it will actually call `MyString::pattern` instead. `String::pattern` is actually implemented as a [primitive](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/bootstrap/string.rb#L14-17), with which I am not very familiar, but I believe the interesting bit is [this](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/vm/builtin/string.cpp#L1219):

```
String* s = state->new_object_dirty<String>(as<Class>(self));
//                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In [JRuby](http://JRuby.Org/), I think the magic is [here](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyString.java#L1189):

```
RubyString result = new RubyString(context.runtime, getMetaClass(), bytes);
//                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Interestingly, in [Topaz](http://TopazRuby.Com/), the class is `String`, not `MyString`:

```
topaz -e 'class MyStr < String; end; p MyStr.new.*(2).class'
# => String
```

It's implemented [here](https://github.com/topazproject/topaz/blob/master/topaz/objects/stringobject.py#L165-166) (I think):

```
  def mul(self, space, storage, times):
      return space.newstr_fromchars(self.unerase(storage) * times)
```

As it turns out, the [ISO Ruby Language Specification](http://iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=59579) has this to say about `String#*`:

> Create a direct instance *S* of the class `String` the content of which is *C* repeated *n* times.

Note how it says "direct instance", i.e. not an instance of a subclass of `String`, but an instance of `String` itself. So, at first glance, it seems that YARV, JRuby, and Rubinius violate the spec here. But, this spec is for `String#*`, not for `MyString#*`, so the question is: does this spec also apply if the method is inherited by a subclass? Is it the responsibility of the subclass to maintain the invariant in the spec, or is it the responsibility of `String#*` to maintain the invariant even in the event that `String` is subclassed but `String#*` is not overridden?